# Repaint child window's controls using win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a main window which has a child window which in turn have a child window and a button. When i restore the window from taskbar the button and third child window refuse to display. I tried using RedrawWindow() on the child first, and then the grand child and the button but didnt work. So far it looks like there is no connection between the child window and its child cos the parent is responsible for repainting its child, but the child has no duty. How do i repaint child window's controls / child window (child of a child), during parent (main window) repaint. That is after restore of parent using Win32 API.

I created a control class as the entry point of the app and to oversee all other classes(Screen class- for GUI, Database class...), the Screen class have all the child creation codes in it. This how:

```
//MainControl Class

#include <tchar.h>
#include "Screen.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "FreeImage.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")
#pragma comment(lib,"gdi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"FreeImage.lib")




const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";
Screen display;
HWND welcomScreenHndl, menuScreenHndl, butt;

// Function prototypes
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT messages, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);




int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                    int nCmdShow){

WNDCLASSEX wc;
HWND hwnd;
MSG Msg;

// Registering the Window Class.
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style = 0;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);


if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)){
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

// Creating the Window.
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, g_szClassName,
    "Prison Management System",
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    100, 30, 750, 700, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if(hwnd == NULL){
    MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
    return 0;
}


// Creating Other Windows with Scree class object.
welcomScreenHndl = display.welcomeScreen(hwnd, hInstance);//Child to Main Window
menuScreenHndl = display.menuScreen(welcomScreenHndl, hInstance);//grand child


ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

// The message loop.
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Here is the Screen class:  // Screen Class

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>



class Screen{

char winClassName[20];
public:

HWND welcomeScreen(HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance);
HWND menuScreen(HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance);

};



HWND Screen::welcomeScreen(HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance){

    GetClassName(parent, winClassName, 20);

    HWND hwndpan = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            winClassName,
            "",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            0, 20, 745, 695,
            parent, NULL, hInstance/*GetModuleHandle(NULL)*/, NULL);


    return hwndpan;
}

HWND Screen::menuScreen(HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance){

    HWND hwndpan = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            winClassName,
            "",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
            0, 100, 745, 695,
            parent, NULL, hInstance/*GetModuleHandle(NULL)*/, NULL);

    return hwndpan;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like something in your app is preventing `WM_PAINT` messages from being dispatched to the child/grandchild correctly.

Comment: Check that your `GetMessage` loop doesn't specify a particular window. If that's not the issue, try setting the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style on the parent window.

Comment: We **really need to see some code**. Start with `WM_CREATE` and `WM_PAINT`. [Here](http://pastebin.com/Pmis9VQx) is the subclassing example I have described earlier. Just create `default Win32 project` in `Visual Studio` and modify the code in your main `.cpp` file with mine. Hopefully it will help you to find out what is wrong with your code. Without seeing your code there is nothing else anyone can do. Good luck and best regards.

Comment: Thanks to you all. @Jonathan I dont think so. The subclass code didnt run. I'll edit and put my code.

Comment: as for 'code' WM_CREATE 'code' and 'code' WM_PAINT 'code' nothing is in there.

Comment: I really wish to help, but your design is not understandable to me.It seems that you wanted to create main window, then show "welcome window", and then show menu. If your project is not commercial/copyright protected, can you upload it somewhere so we can have a look? You can remove the irrelevant parts, just upload a sample project that illustrates the problem. Also, I have spotted a mistake-`CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW` do not belong in the call to `CreateWindowEx`. The very least you can do is removing them-hopefully that fixes your problem, but I doubt. Best regards.

Comment: A little talk on my deleted post. Users on this forum should try to vote post with good judgement. Some questions do not require code display at first.  It is when a sure answer is given and the problem still persist that can be requested. @AlwaysLearningNewStuff you are a good teacher and helper, i moved my troubles to #code#project# and you followed and you've seen that I'm not the type of programmer that looks for code snippets. Thanks a million.

Comment: @AnthonyOyovwe: I have responded to your comments on CP. Thank you for your compliments. Best regards.